\copy does not work when same table is joined twice next to each other
I have a query that runs on cron and what it will do is run \copy on a query..
I applied the an update on the query last day then the next day it didn't generate a report
turns out when the query is like this it won't generate the report but when I run the query
on pgadmin it works and no syntax error is returned
Example1:
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
 INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE2.ID = TABLE1.ID
 LEFT JOIN TABLE3 ON TABLE3.ID = TABLE1.ID AND TABLE3.COLUMN1 <> ''
 LEFT JOIN TABLE3 T3 ON T3.ID = TABLE1.ID AND T3.COLUMN2 <> 0
 LEFT JOIN TABLE4 ON TABLE4.ID = TABLE1.ID

But when I changed the order of T3 like this the cron job generates the report..
Example2:
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE2.ID = TABLE1.ID
LEFT JOIN TABLE3 ON TABLE3.ID = TABLE1.ID AND TABLE3.COLUMN1 <> ''
LEFT JOIN TABLE4 ON TABLE4.ID = TABLE1.ID
LEFT JOIN TABLE3 T3 ON T3.ID = TABLE1.ID AND T3.COLUMN2 <> 0

Does anyone know why it didn't work on the first Example
I wanted to know the reason why the first example didn't work and why changing the order of the table works

Both SELECT queries do the same. It's unclear how \copy comes into this, and what "it won't generate the report" means exactly, and what your version of Postgres is.

@ErwinBrandstetter what i mean is it doesnt return the csv file.. also I'm using version 13

Please share your complete psql statement, that's where \copy is used. If your query doesn't find any data, there is nothing to return anyway. Without data it's impossible for us to see if your query is correct.
